# Token String works fine on console but not work on the java endpoint

Tags: java, token

Hello I've a problem trying to implement jjwt token in java rest. I've a static method to create the token, when I tested it on console works great every time. but when i try to create it on the endpoint (String method) some errors ocurred. The AJAX call works fine, I don't know why whe y display the token on console works fine, and when i try to display it on simple javascript alert(xhr.responseText) on the endpoint just can't do it. I could see that the token is an String, why i cannot display it?.

This is the static method to create the token String:

```
public class ValidateToken{

    public static String createToken(String user){

        Key key = MacProvider.generateKey();
        String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(user).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, key).compact();

    return token;
  }
}
```

This is the test method on console that works great:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String user="TokenTest";

    System.out.println(ValidateToken.createToken(user));
}
```

This is the java endpoint:

```
@Path("/validateToken")
public class Autenticacion_stateless {

  @POST
  @Path("/validate")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  public String createToken(@FormParam("user") String user){

    String response= null;

        try
            {
                ValidateToken.createToken(user);
            }
            catch(SignatureException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("It does'nt work.");
                }

    return response;
 }

}
```

This is the AJAX call:

```
function createToken(){

user= document.getElementById("user");

var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
var url= "/Proyecto_Final_AAB/rest/validateToken/validate";

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("user="+user.value);
}
```

This is the html file with the input text:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/token.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="user">

    <input type="button" value="send" onclick="createToken()">

</body>
</html>
```

[This is the image with the token on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS6Ap.jpg)

```
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Proyecto_Final_AAB' did not find a matching property.
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server built:          Jan 18 2017 20:54:42 UTC
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server number:         7.0.75.0
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Name:               Windows 7
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Version:            6.1
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Architecture:          x86
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
abr 19, 2017 9:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\user\Downloads\eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32\eclipse;;.
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8079"]
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8008"]
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 836 ms
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio Catalina
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
abr 19, 2017 9:19:14 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFORMACIÓN: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [146] milliseconds.
abr 19, 2017 9:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
abr 19, 2017 9:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMACIÓN: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
abr 19, 2017 9:19:16 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFORMACIÓN: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
abr 19, 2017 9:19:18 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFORMACIÓN: Root resource classes found:
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.AutenticarSuperAdministrador
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores.AdminSeg
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores.SuperAdmin
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores.Administradores
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.AutenticarAdministradorVuelo
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.Autenticacion_stateless
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.AutenticarAdministradorSeguridad
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores.AdminVuelos
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.AutenticarUsuario
  class org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores.Empleados
abr 19, 2017 9:19:18 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFORMACIÓN: Provider classes found:
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper
  class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
  class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
abr 19, 2017 9:19:18 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFORMACIÓN: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:42 PM'
abr 19, 2017 9:19:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8079"]
abr 19, 2017 9:19:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8008"]
abr 19, 2017 9:19:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 5375 ms
abr 19, 2017 9:19:34 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
GRAVE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value.<clinit>(JsonInclude.java:204)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:44)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:549)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:465)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.<clinit>(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:42)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder(Jwts.java:116)
    at org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.ValidarToken.crearToken(ValidarToken.java:25)
    at org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.Autenticacion_stateless.createToken(Autenticacion_stateless.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

abr 19, 2017 9:19:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [Servlet_Aeropuerto] en el contexto con ruta [/Proyecto_Final_AAB] lanzó la excepción [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS] con causa raíz
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value.<clinit>(JsonInclude.java:204)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:44)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:549)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:465)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.<clinit>(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:42)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder(Jwts.java:116)
    at org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.ValidarToken.crearToken(ValidarToken.java:25)
    at org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.Autenticacion_stateless.createToken(Autenticacion_stateless.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my pom.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  4.0.0

```
<dependencies>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
                <version>1.19</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JJWT Token dependencias de github -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0.pr1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0.pr1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0.pr1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.16</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>

  <groupId>
    Proyecto_Final_AAB</groupId>
  <artifactId>Proyecto_Final_AAB</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>


      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I've already add a screenshot with the dependencies and the reference libraries added manually:
[Maven dep and Manually libs added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhZVT.jpg)

Comment: is there any exception in the web browser console or application log. please share the stack trace.

Comment: You could probably get help if you use the correct keyword. Is this Java or Javascript?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are doing anything with the token created in the endpoint `Autenticacion_stateless#createToken()`.  What behavior are you expecting, and what error do you get?

Comment: Now i am going to edit the question with the error log

Comment: I just posted the errors on the question, if anyone could see it would be great @RajithPemabandu

Comment: @les-hazlewood if you could see it, could be great, thanks you.

Comment: Whenever an exception is caught, it must be rethrown or printed. You simply swallow the exception, hence "some errors ocurred". Try rethrowing the exception wrapped RuntimeException, that lets the web server log it. Or you could just print it using `ex.printStackTrace` method.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a library clash between the jackson libs jjwt uses and the one you import either manually or through other jars.

If you go to a [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.7.0), you'll see down below that JJWT depends on jackson-databind. (v 2.8.2) in this case.

Check what version of that you actually have in your classpath and I'll bet it's different.

If you still can't figure it out, try [this tool](http://jhades.github.io/).

Comment: Yesterday I removed some old jackson libraries before 2.0, and token start to work fine on the console, so I belive that should be working fine on the endpoint. If you suggest that could be wrong on that, i can edit my question and add the pon.xml file.

Comment: If your end point still throws the exception, add the pom file to your post. I am pretty sure I'm right. Although, the extra jackson libs probably come from your app server. Bottom line, check the actual jar files and make sure the jackson libs you have don't clash.

Comment: Yes, i am on it. I'm going to edit my question with pom.xml and the reference libraries that I've added manually.

Comment: I recently edited the question with the pom file and the screenshot of the maven dependencies and the manual libraries added.